# Using Block in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a doubt with Using(){}. I know that it uses Idisposable interface. So if I write in linq to entities:

```
Using(objectconext context=new objectcontext())
{
   throw new Exception();
}
```

will the objectcontext still be disposed and the existing connection be closed or it will remain there alive.
Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement expands to a `try` `finally` block.  So when the exception is thrown, the `finally` block in the `using` statement should execute.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx:

> The using statement ensures that
>   Dispose is called even if an exception
>   occurs while you are calling methods
>   on the object.

What happens next is another matter. As *spender* points out in his answer, the `DataContext` has no obligation to close the connection it is using, nor do you need to be concerned about it (since the `DataContext` should properly manage the connection for you).

Under certain conditions, your thrown exception can be swallowed silently by the `try` `finally` block. See here: http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/51/c%23-using-blocks-can-swallow-exceptions.  This shouldn't affect you, though.

Comment: @paolo: You should be OK as long as Dispose doesn't throw an exception.  If that happens, the exception thrown by Dispose takes precedence (which is proper, IMO).

Answer (score 2):

The connection won't necessarily be closed, as this is managed elsewhere.

Comment: Hi spender, thanks for your time. What should be the best practice then when using entity framework?

Comment: The Context should be regarded as ephemeral. The framework is designed so that you can use them in a very throw-away fashion. Connections are pooled and reused. Your usage is fine.

Answer (score 1):

From [try-finally on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The finally block is useful for
>   cleaning up any resources allocated in
>   the try block as well as running any
>   code that must execute even if there
>   is an exception. Control is always
>   passed to the finally block regardless
>   of how the try block exits.

Since "using" is syntactic sugar for a `try {} finally { /*calling IDisposable.Dispose() */ }` block, using should guarantee that your object is properly disposed even in case of exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because your are using `USING` keyword **it will be disposed** even if there is an **exception**.

*It's discussed in this thread*: [C# "Using" Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149609/c-using-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be disposed. Using is similar like Try-Catch-Finally and disposal of objects in Finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Dispose will [close the connection if it was opened by the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738763.aspx).